# "real funny" vs "really funny"

Tags: word-usage, connotations

I was wondering why "real funny" is usually used sarcastically (to my experience, almost exclusively so) while the related phrase, "really funny" doesn't carry the connotation.

> [A makes fun of B]
>  B: Yeah, real funny.
>  ---
>  [A
> makes a joke that B likes]
>  B: Ha, that's really funny!

Is this just a common usage that only proliferated for "real funny", or is there some etymology behind this?

Comment: idk how this came about [hence not an answer] but it was definitely US-originated. Dropping the 'ly' from adverbs would never be done in the UK 30 years ago, it was only ever heard in US TV/film. We've since adopted it too. It's never 'correct' but it's become idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [A makes fun of B]
>  B: Yeah, real funny.
>  ---
>  [A
> makes a joke that B likes]
>  B: Ha, that's really funny!

As far as I know, there's no real etymology as to why the phrase 'Yeah, real funny' has a sarcastic connotation. However, you can consider this to be a modern phrase used by many people. To answer your question, it's just used commonly among the public to denote that something wasn't really funny in their opinion. Another example includes the word 'totally' and rarely 'definitely'. Oftentimes, the phrase is intended to be sarcastic like the below:

> I totally agree with you

> I definitely clean my room up every single day

Hope this helped!